# Compare two images using OpenCV in Android

Tags: android, opencv, android-camera, image-comparison

I need to develop an app that captures the picture using Camera API and compare that picture with all other pictures in the database. For comparing the images i'm going to use OpenCV. But i'm new to openCV. I have set up the openCV in Eclipse. But i don't know what functions can be used to compare two images. i'm stuck here. 
Comparison here is, lets say i take a picture of a plant, and i have a picture of the same plant in my database but in some other height, width and position. Here i should compare the pictures and say that they are similar. How can i achieve this kind of comparison? Help me!

Comment: Not every single API, but went through some of it which is referred in some SO question and answer. i don't know have any clue how to start of with it. Like how i should process the image and the steps to be followed for it.

Comment: I think you should see http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/AndroidSamples